# Custom button on navigation bar stops working

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created a custom button in `ViewDidLoad` that shows a new view (via downALevel):

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay target:self action:@selector(downALevel:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
```

The view loads fine and the button works.  When I return to the view, the buttons appears to be disabled and won't work.  I'm using Xcode 6; this wasn't an issue in previous versions.

Any ideas?

- (IBAction)downALevel:(id)sender{

  [self showWaiting];

  [self performSelectorInBackground:(@selector(callGrouper4)) withObject:nil];

}

-(void)showWaiting{

```
waitAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please Wait...." message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];


[waitAlert show];     

UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];


indicator.center = CGPointMake(waitAlert.bounds.size.width / 2, waitAlert.bounds.size.height - 50); 

[indicator startAnimating];
[waitAlert addSubview:indicator];
```

}

-(void)callGrouper4{ // down a level

```
@autoreleasepool {

    float progressPercent;
    NSString *progMsg;
    NSString *curProgress;
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter2 = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter2 setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    [formatter2 setMinimumFractionDigits:0];
    [formatter2 setMaximumFractionDigits:0];

    NSManagedObjectContext *newMoc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator2 = [[self managedObjectContext] persistentStoreCoordinator];
    [newMoc setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator2];
    [newMoc setUndoManager:nil];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"TrialBalance" inManagedObjectContext:newMoc]];
```

......lots of data manipulation......

//finish

```
    [waitAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:TRUE];

    reportBalances2 = nil;



    Level2ActivityViewController *newController = [[Level2ActivityViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Level2ActivityViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    [newController setManagedObjectContext:newMoc];
    [newController setHeaderTitle:headerTitle];
    [newController setLevelToQuery:@"Obj2"];
    [newController setDdSumOrDetail:ddSumOrDetail];
    [newController setOrgNameVar:orgNameVar];
    [newController setPeriodNum:periodNum];
    [newController setReportMode:reportMode];
    [newController setSectionSort:@"obj1"];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:newController animated:YES];


}
```

UPDATE 1
Let's call the first view A and the new view B.  I just discovered that if B has the same code to create a custom button, then the button on A is disabled.  If the code is absent from B then all is well.  I'm very confused??!!

Comment: Could you show us the code of `downALevel:`?

Comment: Are you doing something when your view controller disappears which could coz this issue?

Comment: downALevel is nearly 900 lines of code that manipulates data that is then presented in the new view.  The same code (downALevel) is also executable via a left swipe gesture which works fine, whereas the button only works once.  When I return to the original view, the button appears to be disabled but the swipe gesture still works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are violating a couple of thread responsibilities here!

First, you are calling `performSelectorInBackground:` but inside the `callGrouper4` method, you are not switching back to the main thread before pushing a view controller. Keep in mind that UIKit is not thread safe. This could case strange behaviour like the one you are seeing!

Also you are creating an `NSManagedObjectContext` without using the `initWithConcurrencyType:` api. This means your managed object context is using the `NSConfinementConcurrencyType` concurrency type. This means you are not allowed to pass this context to another thread, but you are assigning it to the new view controller, which will, most likely, make calls to it on the main thread, which is not the thread it was created in.

When creating your `NSManagedObjectContext` you are also setting the coordinator like this: `[[self managedObjectContext] persistentStoreCoordinator]`. I would assume the managed object context you are querying here has been created in the same way, probably on another thread. In this case it is not safe to make this call either!

While issue two and three might result in unexpected behaviour later on, issue one could easily be the problem why your UI behaves strangely.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much!  I thought that once the code executed, it automatically switched back to the main thread but I have followed your advice on all issues, made changes and everything appears to be working perfectly.  I'm new to iOs coding and really do appreciate the time/effort that experienced coders like yourself devote to helping people like me.  It's my aim to get proficient enough to be able to help others also:)

Comment: @Eusi if you are new to iOS, you might want to dig into grand central dispatch instead of using the (old) perform selector methods. Its a bit more complex but gives you way more control and because of the block based api you are not losing context with every queue (something like threads) change.